# Rebuild media file from wireshark logs

Tags: streaming, wireshark, rtsp, darwin

Is it possible to recreate the media file from the captured wireshark logs. Is there any doc which explains how this needs to be done. 
I am doing RTSP based streaming from my darwin test server. So I want to compare the Quality of the original and the streamed file.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to capture stream in something like VLC / streamripper and compare then?

Comment: Thanks Axarydax for your comments,  but I have never used streamripper is there any doc available for that? Also how VLC can be used. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familar with Darwin Streaming Servers but generally RTSP is only for establishing the RTP stream. The direction of RTP packets is normally in one direction (ignoring the ACK-packages for TCP).

For comparing the files I would use a tool suggested by all other users.

But to answer your question for wireshark:

1. filter you stream for the destination ip by using 'ip.addr eq '
2. look for your RTP or UDP packages from the RTSP-server
3. in case you see UDP-packages: right click on the package->'Decode As' and choose 'RTP' in Transport tab
4. choose from context menu 'follow UDP stream'

now you have the whole RTP-stream without RTP headers.

But keep in mind that in H.264 you have packetization which gives you extra bytes in the displayed stream. You cannot compare this with the original file!!
Look [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984) in chapter 5.4. for further description.

Better use the tools mentioned by the others!

Comment: Hi jenseb, Thanks for your explaination. I have tired with the options suggested by other users as well. Like with VLC the size of the captured file is more then the original source file so that option is also not possible.  Is there any possible way in which this can be achieved.

Comment: when nothing works suggested by the others and me I fear the easiest way is to code your own receiver and detect every single frame for comparing it with the original one! Both Server and client are normally adding video config data regularly for having a robust stream.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible the way you hope, as RTSP is a sort of conversation between a client and a server (or servers). To recreate the RTSP session you would have to recreate all of this two-way traffic - it is not really comparable to opening a file in a video player.

I think you will find it easier to use [VLC](http://videolan.org/vlc) to stream the rtsp:// link and save it to a file. The stream will be transcoded while saving, so if you need a "true" comparison to the original file, you will want to use a lossless video codec for transcoding, and the output file could be very large.

Comment: Thanks ithcy for your comments. One doubt though as I am using VLC only to stream the media file how it can be saved can u explain more ? "easier to use VLC to stream the rtsp:// link and save it to a file."

Comment: VLC can stream and save to a file at the same time. You get this option when you open a network stream in the VLC GUI. It can also be done from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ostinato, You should be able to replay the file and capture using VLC.